# Twitter badge wont go away

Tags: twitter

On the Twitter icon (both in my home screen and in my app list) I can see a badge with a "4", but no matter what I do, that badge will not go away, no matter what I do. All my notifications and mentions have been cleared!

What can I do to fix it?

```
INFO:
OnePlus 5T
Android 9
OxygenOS 9.0.9
Home screen App: [Evie launcher][1]
```

Comment: These may be unread tweets outside the limiting factor of the phone app, which IIRC is about 200. Does it go away if you bring up a browser and scroll farther into the past to assure the system older items are all read? You may have to go so far into the past where this problem first occurred, 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, etc.

Comment: I cant review all the 200 latest tweets... I need a way to mark them as read

Comment: Reddit posts suggest this may be because of multiple account usage on the same device. Is this the case?

Comment: No it's not the case

Answer (score 0):

Notification badges will show counts for multiple types of notifications, which might be displayed in various places. Try long-pressing the icon with the notification badge; this should bring up a context menu that may list additional notices. You can swipe to clear individual notices. You might also see a "clear badge" command to clear all notifications.

If that doesn't work, try clearing the app cache:

1. Open the settings for the app:

   - Fast way to get to app settings: long-press the app icon and tap "ⓘ".
   - If there is no "ⓘ":

     1. Open Settings
     2. Go to App settings (the exact location varies). Make sure "All apps" or "Installed apps" is listed.
     3. Scroll down to & tap Twitter.
2. Tap "Storage"
3. Tap "Clear cache"

Comment: Doesn't work! Cache cleared yet badge remains.
Unread notification count badge is off!